# Setup cgminer on Ubuntu 12.04 (im getting libudev.so.1 not found error)

Tags: miner-configuration, cgminer, ubuntu, error

I have read and read and read over the internet but noone seems to have problem like this.

Im trying to setup cgminer on my Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit) desktop but i failed. Downloaded cgminer from url http://ck.kolivas.org/apps/cgminer/ read all the instructions but not working.

The error im getting when i try to start it is

```
./cgminer: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any help? btw im on Nvidia graphic if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, NVidia Graphics card utilization versus naked CPU does help, quite a bit.

Breath. Take a step back.  Make sure you're running as an administrator. Try bashing

> sudo apt-get install libudev1

Use this wiki http://www.distrogeeks.com/install-cgminer-latest-ubuntu/

Don't get discouraged! It's tough but we've all gotta learn sometime, no better way to do it but to Do It.